# AmCharts floating bar with dates on x-axis

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I have numerous items (surveys in my case) which have a certain "opened time". Using AmCharts I'd like to display all surveys over time as a floating bar chart. The beginning of the floating bar should be the date when a survey is open for filling in, the end of a bar should be the openUntil date for that survey.

I'm reading the [API documentation](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart) and am trying to combine the examples for a [Floating bar chart](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/floating-bar-chart/) and [XY chart with date based axis](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/xy-chart-date-based-axis/). While my y-axis is populated with the registered surveys, the floating bars (and also x-axis) won't show.

The dataLoader plugin fetches the following data:

```
[{
    "survey":"Test Survey 2",
    "openFrom":"2016-08-01",
    "openUntil":"2016-08-31",
    "color":"#ff9900"
 },
 {
    "survey":"Test Survey 1",
    "openFrom":"2016-05-06",
    "openUntil":"2016-06-06",
    "color":"#ff9900"
}]
```

The implementation code I have so far:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart('chart-container', {
    'type' : 'serial',
    'dataLoader' : {
        'url' : urlToFetchDataFrom
    },
    'language': 'nl',
    'categoryAxis' : {
        'position': 'right'
    },
    'valueAxis' : [{
        'type': 'date',
        'minimumDate': new Date(2016, 1, 1),
        'minimumDate': new Date(2016, 12, 31)
    }],
    'categoryField' : 'survey',
    'graphs' : [{
        'type': 'column',
        'dateFormat': 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        'openField' : 'openFrom',
        'valueField' : 'openUntil'
    }],
    'rotate': true,
    'dataDateFormat': 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});
```

The chart renders as:
[image: this]

Any suggestions on how to make a floating bar chart with date boundaries plotted over a period of time on the x-axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code, that prevent the chart from showing up correctly:

1) `valueAxes` is misspelled as "valueAxis".

2) You have `minimumDate` set twice. The second one should probably be `maximumDate`.

3) Dates in JavaScript are zero-based. So January is 0, December - 11.

The following code should make the chart appear as expected:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart('chart-container', {
    'type' : 'serial',
    'dataLoader' : {
        'url' : urlToFetchDataFrom
    },
    'language': 'nl',
    'categoryAxis' : {
        'position': 'right'
    },
    'valueAxes' : [{
        'type': 'date',
        'minimumDate': new Date(2016, 0, 1),
        'maximumDate': new Date(2016, 11, 31)
    }],
    'categoryField' : 'survey',
    'graphs' : [{
        'type': 'column',
        'dateFormat': 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        'openField' : 'openFrom',
        'valueField' : 'openUntil'
    }],
    'rotate': true,
    'dataDateFormat': 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});
```

Comment: Following one of the other examples I also saw my typo in `axes` and noticed the duplicate `minimumDate`. I did'nt knew about the 0 to 11 range for dates in javascript. Thanks, works like a charm now!

Comment: Excellent. Glad I could help.